# Sort a list of lists

Tags: python, list

I have a list of lists in Python that represents the edges of a graph and I want to sort it, so that the second value of the first list is the same as the first value of the next list. For example I have this list:

```
[('AT', 'TG'), ('GT', 'TG'), ('TG', 'GG'), ('GG', 'GC'), ('GC', 'CG'), ('CG', 'GT'), ('GC', 'CA'), ('TG', 'GC'), ('CA', 'AA'), ('AA', 'AT')]
```

And I want to change the order so that the list is like this:

```
[('AT', 'TG'), ('TG', 'GG'), ('GG', 'GC'), ('GC', 'CG'), ('CG', 'GT'),  ('GT', 'TG'),  ('TG', 'GC'),  ('GC', 'CA'),  ('CA', 'AA'), ('AA', 'AT')]
```

How can i do that?

Comment: What's preventing you?

Comment: well, the fact that i don't know how i guess

Comment: Then please give it a minimal try, or at least share your thoughts as your question is too broad.

Comment: i don't really get how it's too broad, i believe i explained exactly what i wanted to  do and i have the issue that i don't know how so i came here for some help :/

Comment: We *want* to help you. But providing a ready solution to copy-and-paste will not be really helping you. The best way of learning is trying to do a minimal research before asking for a ready solution.

Comment: If the sorting algorithm has several choices (like ('TG', 'GG') and ('TG', 'GC')), which one should it take as next element?

Comment: i believe it's irrelevant, as long as it continues in the right order, like  ('GG', 'GC') after ('TG', 'GG')  and  ('CG', 'GT') after ('TG', 'GC')

Comment: So would this be a valid ordering? [('AT', 'TG'), ('TG', 'GC'), ('GC', 'CA'), ('CA', 'AA'), ('AA', 'AT')]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this helps. It prints all possible "orderings":

```
from collections import defaultdict

l = [('AT', 'TG'), ('GT', 'TG'), ('TG', 'GG'), ('GG', 'GC'), ('GC', 'CG'), ('CG', 'GT'), ('GC', 'CA'), ('TG', 'GC'), ('CA', 'AA'), ('AA', 'AT')]

lookup = defaultdict(set)
for k, v in l:
    lookup[k].add(v)

def sort(l, s):
    k = l[-1][1]
    pairs = set([(k, v) for v in lookup[k]]) - s
    if len(pairs) == 0:
        return [l]
    results = set()
    for k, v in pairs:
        results.update(sort(l + ((k, v), ), s | set([(k, v)])))
    return results

results = sort((('AT', 'TG'), ), set([('AT', 'TG')]))

for result in  results:
    print list(result)
```

Output:

> [('AT', 'TG'), ('TG', 'GG'), ('GG', 'GC'), ('GC', 'CG'), ('CG', 'GT'), ('GT', 'TG'), ('TG', 'GC'), ('GC', 'CA'), ('CA', 'AA'), ('AA', 'AT')]
>
> [('AT', 'TG'), ('TG', 'GC'), ('GC', 'CA'), ('CA', 'AA'), ('AA', 'AT')]
>
> [('AT', 'TG'), ('TG', 'GC'), ('GC', 'CG'), ('CG', 'GT'), ('GT', 'TG'), ('TG', 'GG'), ('GG', 'GC'), ('GC', 'CA'), ('CA', 'AA'), ('AA', 'AT')]
>
> [('AT', 'TG'), ('TG', 'GG'), ('GG', 'GC'), ('GC', 'CA'), ('CA', 'AA'), ('AA', 'AT')]

Comment: Yes it helps a lot, thank you!!